# Represent image form database

Tags: php, html, database

I’d like to represent an image stored in a database every time I press a button. The column name is “solution_path”.
In my code I can represent the image outside the button, but I would like it to appear when I press the button. Part of the code is shown below. I know how to represent images taken from the database, but in this case, I do not know why it’s not working. Can you help me?
I am already connected to the database and to the table I need.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*echo*/ $id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
?>

<div id="centered_B" class="header">

<?php
while($id = $result->fetch_assoc())
    echo '<h1>' . $id["exercise_id"]. ". " . $id["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $id["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $id["image_path"] . '"><br><br>


    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "1" /><img width="550" height="auto" src="' . $id["image_path_A"] . '"/>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "2" /><img width="550" height="auto" src="' . $id["image_path_B"] . '"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "3" /><img width="550" height="auto" src="' . $id["image_path_C"] . '"><br>';


/*var_dump($id)*/
?>


 <button onclick="solutionFunction()" class="button_Solution" >Solution</button>



<div id="solution" style="display: none;">
    This is the solution.
    <img width="500" height="auto" src="<?php echo $id["solution_path"]; ?>" >

</div>



<script>
    function solutionFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("solution");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot change image source in your HTML image tag without page refresh. If you do not want to refresh the page then use AJAX.

Comment: I have added more of my code

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Any errors in your browser console? Probably the function isn't defined in the right place. Try moving the `<script` block above the `<button`. The code itself is fine - see http://jsfiddle.net/hg24d13q/1/

Comment: ADyson  it works when I represent an image that is not stored in the databse, but what I want is to represent `solution_path` from the database. However `image_path` works fine.

Comment: well, what is in `solution_path`? Give us an example of some data which isn't working. Whatever you put into "src" has to be a valid URL (absolute or relative), or a valid base64 string. We can't guess what's in your database, can we.

Comment: When I uncomment `/*var_dump($id)*/` it shows `null`, maybe it's because of that?

Comment: In `solution_path` there's an image. I put the same image as `image_path`

Comment: If your image is inside the database (as a BLOB) and not as a file on the filesystem - then you need a PHP script (**whose** URL you will then put in the IMG tag) which will fetch the image from database and serve it to the browser.

Comment: This is what I put in the database: `update exercises set solution_path = 'img/1s.JPG' where exercise_id = 1;` I know that this is correct

Comment: `$id` is null within your while loop? Seems odd. If there was no row to return it would not even enter the while loop. Does any of the rest of your HTML get shown? You didn't mark where the PHP `while` loop finishes, can you add that? BTW you already used $id for something else earlier...bad practice to reassign the same name to a different purpose. Give that loop variable a different name to avoid confusion ideally.

Comment: The problem is not in the database, because when I change where `image_path` says to `solution_path`, I get the image correctly

Comment: Okay, I reassigned the $id to $row where you told me. But still doesnt work

Comment: And what is the actual HTML that is being output to the browser ?

Comment: Your `while` loop is only one statement long...

Comment: Yes, the rest of my HTML shows correctly. I dont understand when you ask me to mark where the PHP while loop finishes. Can you show me?

Comment: I updated my comment actually, I spotted it. Your while loop is only one statement long because you didn't use any brackets. So after that you're not in the loop anymore, so obviously you can't reference any variables which derive from being in the loop, such as the content of a row.

Comment: HTML shows the `image_path`, exercise_id, title.. everything except `solution_path` inside `<div id="solution" style="display: none;">
    This is the solution.
    <img width="500" height="auto" src="<?php echo $id["solution_path"]; ?>" >

</div>`

Comment: Where shout I put my brackets? I put them here but still doesn't work: `<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<h1>' . $row["exercise_id"]. ". " . $row["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $row["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $row["image_path"] . '"><br><br>


    ...

}
/*var_dump($id)*/
?>`

Comment: Are you only getting 1 result? You could eliminate the `while` and just assign `$id = $result->fetch_assoc();`... then you use that one result for the rest of the page.

Comment: @ana You mentioned that when you do the var_dump($id) the solution_path is null. That is the exact reason why nothing being displayed. it needs to be the path to your image.

Check your data entry, make sure it's being populated correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right Dpolehonski , how can I solve it?

Comment: Okey I delated the `WHILE` and just added `$id = $result->fetch_assoc();` as  IncredibleHat told me... and it works!! Thank you everyone for you help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving my comment as an answer for you to close your question with ;)

If you are only dealing with one result row for that specific page build, you should get rid of the `while` loop and simply assign the one result row to your `$id` variable, to use throughout the page.

So change this one line:

```
while($id = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

To just:

```
$id = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Now `$id` will persist through the page generation, and your lower echo of `$id["solution_path"]` should present you with the solution image url string you need.

---

The reason your original code was not working, is a `while` has the specific behavior of 'wiping out' the assigned variable on the last loop iteration (thus causing the condition to turn 'false' and end the loop).

Also, since you did not have curly braces, that `while` was only controlling the immediate following `echo` line. This then meant the further echo you had for the `$id["solution_path"]` variable, would have been echoing a null result. If you had php error reporting fully enabled, you may had seen a warning about undefined index too.

I hope that helps you out!